# /etc/fstab skip on error

Tags: fstab

Can I set an /etc/fstab with options=auto to be skipped if mounting fails?

The manual says, it will break the boot process if an entry with options=auto fails.

Without auto, it does not automatically mount the device on boot.

So how to make the auto entry to be ignored on failures?

Comment: Related: [How do I avoid the “S to Skip” message on boot?](http://askubuntu.com/q/120/78223) at Ubuntu SE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I created a partition called `/dev/sdb1` in my Ubuntu VM. But I didn’t create a filesystem for this partition and so of course it will not get mounted.

Then put following entry in `fstab`.

```
/dev/sdb1   /mnt/       auto    defaults,nobootwait     0   2
```

And rebooted VM. Server got rebooted with following error msg in `syslog`

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ grep sdb1 /var/log/syslog
Jan 11 16:32:58 ubuntu-vm kernel: [    2.263540]  sdb: sdb1
Jan 11 16:32:59 ubuntu-vm kernel: [    4.403527] EXT3-fs (sdb1): error: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sdb1.
Jan 11 16:32:59 ubuntu-vm kernel: [    4.410341] EXT4-fs (sdb1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
Jan 11 16:32:59 ubuntu-vm kernel: [    4.413978] FAT-fs (sdb1): bogus number of reserved sectors
Jan 11 16:32:59 ubuntu-vm kernel: [    4.414073] FAT-fs (sdb1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

What is [`nobootwait`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/fstab.5.html):

`nobootwait` can be applied to non-remote filesystems to explicitly instruct `mountall(8)` not  to hold up the boot for them.

Comment: nobootwait doesn't work any longer in 16.04

Comment: On rhel/centos 7, the nofail flag works

Comment: What is the correct flag to use on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @AaronFranke , try: nofail,errors=continue

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be better to write a script to mount something after boot?
For example, put string with `noauto` to `fstab` and mount it via `rc.local`

Answer (score 1):

For some flavors `nobootwait` and for for example `xfs` file systems no work

Below work with UUID

```
UUID=718ef17e-5502-4a74-81fe-930d21f5507d /data xfs rw,noquota,nofail  0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your distro, but usually booting just waits with a timeout and then will boot without mounting. You can mount it automatically on run time using an `udev` rule, e.g. on pluggin in.

To bind directories in fstab use:

```
/from    /to   none bind 0 0
```

Comment: debian 6 and it's a `mount --bind dirA directoryB` that i'd like to automate.

Comment: @Steffen grub is never involved with fstab at run time.

Comment: @ledy: Did you try to bind in fstab with e.g. /opt/var_log             /var/log                 none    bind    0 0?

Also you could consider to place a symlink.

Comment: You should definitely edit your post since grub has absolutely nothing to do with mounting.